# Is it possible to have less users in SandBox than exist in PROD?

Tags: sandbox, licenses

I'm looking to reduce the cost of a FULL Sandbox.

The Production Org has 20 users, but I only need 2 or 3 in the SandBox.

Is it possible to purchase SandBox licenses for say 3 users, create the Sandbox from Prod and then deactivate the unwanted / unlicensed users?

Comment: Thanks for the answers @sfdcfox and Bob Buzzard - Makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandboxes are provisioned as an organization feature; either you have one (or more), or you don't. As such, you can't get a "less expensive" sandbox by having one with fewer licenses. You can get a configuration-only sandbox, which is less expensive, or even a developer sandbox. The full sandbox costs as much as it does because it replicates all of your data. If you can spare not having a full copy of your data, you can have significant savings.

Answer (score 2):

Full sandbox costs are a percentage of your production costs, rather than priced separately based on the users/features enabled.

Where the concept of de-activating users would get interesting is that storage size is based on user licenses, so if you reduced your licenses down to the minimum it could be that the org wouldn't have enough space for the data copied as part of a full sandbox refresh!